# Reduce the size/length of an array to a certain size/length

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array: `var array = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i']`
I want the array to be a length of 3, but I don't want to remove the consecutive elements. I want to remove elements evenly from an array.

Since `array.length` is 9, I want to remove 6 elements from it and I always want to keep the first element. so in this case, `var array` would be like `['a', 'e', 'i']`

I was doing like this so far:

```
var extraLength = array.length - 3;
var eachVal = Math.round(array.length/extraLength);

for (var j = 0; j < extraLength; j++){
  for(var i = array.length -1; i >= 0; i-- ) {
    if (i == eachVal*j && i != 0) {
      array.splice(i, 1)
    }
  }
}
```

This gives an error saying `array.splice is not a function`.

Also, as I write this, I realized that this only works when `array.length/extraLength` is an even number, so in the example above, it does not work.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What happens if you have 5 items and you want to end up with 2 (but as you said you want to keep the first one)? Which one you would like to leave? :)

Comment: @AndreyPopov yea that is true. in my case,  i am using this when the length of array is more than 50, but still I am guessing that this cannot be achieved

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This gives an error saying `array.splice is not a function`.

There is no error, at least with the code you presented in the question. See the snippet below for the result of your code:

```js
var array = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i'];
var extraLength = array.length - 3;
var eachVal = Math.round(array.length/extraLength);

for (var j = 0; j < extraLength; j++){
  for(var i = array.length -1; i >= 0; i-- ) {
    if (i == eachVal*j && i != 0) {
      array.splice(i, 1)
    }
  }
}
console.log(array);
```

---

> I want the array to be a length of 3, but I don't want to remove the
>   consecutive elements. I want to remove elements evenly from an array.
>
> Since array.length is 9, I want to remove 6 elements from it and I
>   always want to keep the first element. so in this case, var array
>   would be like ['a', 'e', 'i']

But, this only one use-case. How do you want to handle odd/even sized arrays? I assume, your basic requirement is to remove elements with some delta based on the length of the array and the desired resulting size. And you would be fine by *truncating* the trailing elements.

To do that would be easy by dividing the `length` of the array by your `desired size` and `floor`ing it to avoid fractions. Adding one to that will allow you to have a delta `step factor` which is suitable for odd sized arrays.

Once done that, you just iterate the array with a `step` size of your calculated delta factor.

**Example**:

```js
var array = [
      ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i'], 
      ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h'], 
      ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
    ], 
    factor, result, desiredSize = 3;

for (i=0; i < array.length; i++) {
  // calculate the delta factor
  factor = Math.floor(array[i].length / desiredSize) + 1;
  factor = (desiredSize % 2 === 0) ? --factor : factor;
  result = [];

  // iterate with the step size of the calculated facor
  for (j = 0; j < array[i].length; j = j + factor) {
    result.push(array[i][j]);
  }
  console.log(result);
}
```

In the above example, I am using a nested array to show multiple arrays of differing lengths to keep the code size compact. Check the console to see the result for each of the arrays.

**Edit**:

Changed the code to take into account if the `desiredSize` is an even number. Have to just rollback the increment on the `floor`ed delta factor. This will make it more evenly distributed. Thank you *@Andrey Popov* for the comment.

Comment: Great answer! I was going to write the very same, but I found one strange thing - the `desiredSize` is hardcoded to `3`. What happens if it changes? For example which 2 items will you pick from the last array (5 elements) if you NEED to keep the first one? :)

Comment: A good point @AndreyPopov. The even desired-size will push the delta by one. Let me see if I can fix that to be more evenly distributed as stated by the Op.

Comment: I think it's a matter of interpretation. Because the most evenly distributed 2 items from a 5 items array would be 2nd and 4th, not 1st and 5th (or 3rd). So I guess your code is good enough :)

Comment: @AndreyPopov: Thanks. Edited the answer to add that scenario. Per Op the first element is required, so have to be 1st and 4th and sacrifice the trailing ones. :)

Comment: And yes, this will fall flat if the `desiredSize` is more that `half+1` of the `length`. That is up to the Op to figure out. They have been warned ;)

Comment: @Abhitalks check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44180303/equally-popping-array-keys-based-on-dates