# Equally popping array keys based on dates

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array that looks like this:

```
[numbers] => Array
    (
        [2017-05-14] => 319594
        [2017-05-15] => 319774
        [2017-05-16] => 319962
        [2017-05-17] => 320135
        [2017-05-18] => 320304
        [2017-05-19] => 320459
        [2017-05-20] => 320590
        [2017-05-21] => 320752
        [2017-05-22] => 320882
        [2017-05-23] => 320991
        [2017-05-24] => 321093
        [2017-05-25] => 321144
        [2017-05-26] => 323124
        [2017-05-27] => 324534
        [2017-05-28] => 325123
        [2017-05-29] => 326453
    )
```

The data gets collected every day and will be shown on a line chart using ChartJS. I'm afraid that after a month or two there's too many dates.

Say I want to keep only 6 keys between start and end date. How can I pop the keys equally between the first and last date? This would have to work with arrays of any size.

I have to save the first and last key.

EDIT:

This is what I came up with. Is this the right way?

```
$items = Array(
    "2017-05-14" => 319594,
    "2017-05-15" => 319774,
    "2017-05-16" => 319962,
    "2017-05-17" => 320135,
    "2017-05-18" => 320304,
    "2017-05-19" => 320459,
    "2017-05-20" => 320590,
    "2017-05-21" => 320752,
    "2017-05-22" => 320882,
    "2017-05-23" => 320991,
    "2017-05-24" => 321093,
    "2017-05-25" => 321144,
    "2017-05-26" => 323124,
    "2017-05-27" => 324534,
    "2017-05-28" => 325123
);

$desiredSize = 8 ;
$desiredSize--;

$arrayCount = count($items) - 1;
$factor = $arrayCount / $desiredSize;

echo 0 ."\n";
for ( $i = 1; $i <= $desiredSize; $i++ ) {
    echo floor( $i * $factor ) ."\n";
}
```

Comment: its easy to pop elements, the question is what to take out and leave out ten, what is the logic behind that, and plus, you could just save it in the database and take out how many you want

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of `array_slice`, `array_keys` and `array_search` functions
Lets say you want to get slice of array from key `2017-05-18` to `2017-05-25`. The code would look like this:

```
$arrayKeys = array_keys($array);
$firstElementIndex = array_search('2017-05-18', $arrayKeys);
$lastElementIndex = array_search('2017-05-25', $arrayKeys);
$sliceLenght = $lastElementIndex - $firstElementIndex + 1;
$result = array_slice($array, $firstElementIndex, $sliceLenght, true);
```

Where `$array` is you array of dates

Comment: But what if I want 6 key value pairs between the start and end? The start and end itself would take 2 key value pairs so how can I calculate which 4 pairs do I slice from the between?

Comment: The question is which elements do you need. In my example there are 8 elements between 2017-05-18 and 2017-05-25. You always need the two marginal ones. If you would need 4 max there are 2 options. you can take them from the center of the date range  (2017-05-[21/22]) or  get it with the same distance from each other (2017-05-[20/22])